# XAML for Three way splitter in WPF

Tags: wpf, gridsplitter

I want to split the main window in three way Grid Spliiter same alike outlook style.

and all the controls nested inside in the three window is resized using Grid Splitter.

I am trying to do that using defining Row Definition of Grid and placing each control in Row 1 or column 1..
Its nice to have , if any body has some kind of template to kick start with this kind of layout.. I don't want too complex sample..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a perfect resource - [Build an Outlook 2007 UI Clone](http://blogs.msdn.com/tims/archive/2007/06/13/wpf-hands-on-lab-build-an-outlook-2007-ui-clone.aspx) 
You can download the full demo(OutlookUI HOL Basic - Final), I think it is what you are looking for

**Edit(after comment)**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="1" />
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="3" Width="1" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: I am new to WPF and therefore sample would take more time to understand.. I highly appreciate ,if you could provide me simle XAML that have three side splitter..